# What are good Buddhist portals to conduct a survey on meditation?

Tags: untagged

I am working on wearable tech for meditation. I need to conduct a market research survey for the same. I understand that I cannot conduct a survey on the BSE site. I want to ask that what are good Buddhist portals or other social sites of Buddhist meditation where I can conduct a survey on meditation.

Comment: Please try the [SuttaCentral Watercooler](https://discourse.suttacentral.net/t/about-the-the-watercooler-category/3196), [DhammaWheel](https://www.dhammawheel.com/) - perhaps [Introductions](https://www.dhammawheel.com/viewforum.php?f=10&sid=762ab590467a403a7e139993ec9c82f5), [DharmaWheel](https://www.dharmawheel.net/) - perhaps [Lounge](https://www.dharmawheel.net/viewforum.php?f=36&sid=f21fb7ff280f6023dc21a99885c23dfe), [The Buddhist Centre discussion](https://www.thebuddhistcenter.com/tags/discussion), [Facebook "Buddhism" groups](https://www.facebook.com/search/groups/?q=buddhism) etc.

Comment: Also the [Buddhism Chat Telegram group](https://telegram.me/buddhismchat). You can also ask on our very own [Buddhism.SE chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15162/buddhism) although not many people visit it.

Comment: This question is not displaying links to third party products or marketing websites, hence I feel that it is not spam (as flagged). However, this question is off-topic.

Answer (score 1):

Try dhammawheel.net (14,742 members), dharmawheel.net (11,727 members). Also, have you tried the meditation apps? Insight timer has a large user base (they claim 18 million users). They have “groups” that focus on particular subjects, such as “The Science of Meditation” group (8.3k members). I hope this helps you.

Comment: Thankyou for your answer. I know of Insight Timer but not sure if they will allow me to conduct a survey on their groups.

Comment: You can ask them. Try Maddy Gerrard, Head of Publishing (Maddy at insight.co)

Answer (score 0):

> One    should not make an effort everywhere,
> should not be another's hireling,
> should not live dependent on another,
> should not go about
> as a trader in the Dhamma
> [Paṭisalla Sutta](https://sangham.net/en/tipitaka/sut/kn/uda/uda.6.02.than#fn-2)

*[Not given for stacks, exchange, other world-binding trades, but for an escape from this wheel]*

Comment: Dear Samana, We all have our own ways to share the Dhamma. I am a householder practicing Right Livelihood.

Comment: Selling Dhamma, make a living on the Gems? Such would be wrong livelihood, very wrong, good householder. Look for right, for own long term happiness.